# C# alias/overload a method without explicitly stating its type signature

Tags: c#, methods, alias

I gave some methods a shortened alias name.
As the alias is just another way to call the same exact method it has the same signature (return type + arguments type) and always will.

I'd like to avoid in the developing phase to duplicate each modification to the original method on the alias.
Is there a way to declare the alias so that it's just an alternative name?

```
//the method it's not the actual one, it just illustrates the point
internal static class Utils {
    /*---right now---*/
    public static void ClearScreen(MyType1 Arg1, MyType2 Arg2){
        //method body
    }
    //explicit alias of ClearScreen
    public static void cls(MyType1 Arg1, MyType2 Arg2) => ClearScreen(Arg1,Arg2);
    

    /*---what i'd like---*/
    //way to call ClearScreen so that cls implicitly inherits its arguments //probably unfeasable
    void cls(...args) => CLearScreen(...args);
    
    //literally assigning ClearScreen to cls //again, probably unfeasable as Delegates are strongly typed
    void* cls = &ClearScreen; 
    
    //apply some attribute to the original method //i'm more optimistic about this
    [AliasedAs("cls")]  
    void ClearScreen(MyType1 Arg1, MyType2 Arg2){ ... }
    
    //instruct the compiler as to treat them as the same identifier
    #HeyCompilerSwitchClsWithClearScreenAcrossMyProgram 
}
```

--EDIT--
Answering "WHY do you want to do this?"

it's my 3rd day on C#, so i'm still assessing what one can and cannot do.
To answer you @Guru Stron, i have an utility class and a method that does "full.qualified.type" => "type".
I'll use it for fast dbg and object inspection while learning, which means it need to be short-named.

But what if i want to insert it in persistent logs or long-lasting features? It's better for it to be long-named for mantenaibility.
So the plan is using the full-fledged name for 'production' uses and the fast one for dbg/learning.

I'll may or may not need the same pattern for other utilities too.
(p.s. there's for sure already a built-in method that does that, but i cannot spend days searching/memorizing all the built-ins, i'll learn them on the way)(EDIT It's GetType().Name)
(as there surely is a dbg var inspector in Visual Studio)

Comment: Any particular reason WHY do you want to do this?

Comment: Yes we need an example for the need to have different identifiers for the same thing. Is it to misuse reflection to surface the name of something directly?

Comment: I don't really understand why you want to make these aliases, but the "attribute option" is possible, you should check for "Incremental generators"..

Comment: I'm into my 24th year of working with .NET (i.e. early betas of V1) and I'm still finding "what one can and cannot do". Don't push the boundaries so early. Learn the basics first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any immediate solutions to that problem, but i can think of some sort of workaround:

```
public class Cls
{
    public void AliasedClearScreen(params object[] args) =>
        GetAliased(nameof(ClearScreen), args);

    public void ClearScreen(Type type)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
    }

    void GetAliased(string method, params object[] args)
    {
        var type = Type.GetType(nameof(Cls));
        var myMethod = type.GetMethod(method);
        myMethod.Invoke(this, args);
    }
}
```

and sample usage would be

```
var test = new Cls();
test.AliasedClearScreen(typeof(string));
```

But with this you will loose correct signature of the method.

But another options for you may be [Source Generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview)